# Retrieve Value From MySQL Table and Save in Variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a table (wp_postmeta), which contains four columns (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value). meta_key contains a field called neighborhood_value and the values for neighborhood_value are stored under the meta_value column. How do I retrieve the contents of neighborhood_value from my table and use them as a variable? Any support is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as everything is meta, thecode will also be "meta" :)

**UPDATE** - now when I know what you use to connect to DB I can change my answer to be more specific.

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id=XXX";

$retMeta = array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($results as $resultRow)
{
    if (!isset($retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']]))
    {
        $retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']] = array();
    }
    $retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']][] = $resultRow['meta_value'];
}
```

The resulting $retMeta will be two dimensional array, and then you will be able to access your neighbourhood value by using $retMeta['neighbourhood_value'][0] (of course first you have to check if this is set - `isset($retMeta['neighbourhood_value'])`).

**UPDATE2**

For script imporing data, it'll look like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=XXX";

$retMeta = array();
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($resultRow= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (!isset($retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']]))
    {
        $retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']] = array();
    }
    $retMeta[$resultRow['meta_key']][] = $resultRow['meta_value'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

But you should use WP_Query anyway, to maintain portability (the wp_postmeta doesn't have to be named that way, it can be wp2_postmeta etc).

Comment: That gave me: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function FETCH_QUERY_RESULT_ROW() in /var/www/clients/client4/web4/web/wp-content/plugins/import-rets/RETS_helper.php on line 727

Comment: Well, of course. As I said, this is the "meta" answer, as I don;t really know, what you use to fetch SQL results (mysql_query, WP_Query, PDO...). Well, now I know

Comment: Yeah, sure... Nope, dude. It's WP_Query, as you're writing a WordPress plugin. The DB server might be MySQL, but the function (or rather - object_ used to fetch the data is WP_Query. Sorry I missed wordpress tag on your question, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Nope. I just happen to have it in the plugin folder. The script simply imports listings into a WordPress database, but it uses MySQL_Query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to key a list of keys from meta_value?

I would do this in php: (assuming you are using some sort of framework that supports this construct. This example works with the codeigniter framework))

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct meta_value FROM wp_postmeta"
$result = $db->query($sql)
foreach ($result->reult() as $row) {
  $mydata[] = $row->meta_value;
}
```

$mydata is now array containing all of your meta_value values.

Comment: I only want the values that are in rows with the meta_key of neighborhood_value.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing same as the following.

```
<?php foreach($values as $value)
{
    $myVarname[$value[valuefield]]=$value[valuefield];

}

$myVarname[field1]="Cow";
$myVarname[field2]="dog";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Wordpress template files such as loop.php etc., just use the handy [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function.

Comment: I would, however I need to process them into custom taxinomy's when each item is imported.

Comment: Hmm, you should think about it anyway. Just instead of your/my SQL use get_post_meta(POSTID, 'neighbourhood_value') and then process the meta value as you wish.

Comment: What if I'm not inside the loop. Is get_post_meta() still going to work?

Comment: it has post ID as first parameter so it's independent of the loop magic. You have to have wordpress initialized while running it, though (well, this is obvious as it's a worpres function).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what language you want to use for your variables - but if it happens to be SQL in MySQL, here's how you "Retrieve Value From MySQL Table and Save in Variable":

```
select @var_name := column_name from table_name where other_column = 5;
```

This does the select, and as a side-effect assigns the value of the user variable @var_name to the value of column_name.

or

```
select @var_name := count(*) from other_table where other_column > 5;
```

which sets @var_name to the number of records that matched the condition.